# Dart - Snackbar service - global function vs static class function vs singleton

Tags: flutter, dart, service, wrapper

I would like to create a wrapper around a third-party package Snackbar (the third party Snackbar is simply called like this: `Get.snackbar(title, body, snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);`) in order to decouple my app from the package and be able to easily swap in another Snackbar implementation.

I figure it should be a singleton for performance reasons. I would like to call it like `VpSnackBar(title, body);` ideally. I found how to make a singleton in dart (Vp is my app prefix to identify it was made in my app):

Here I have created this singleton

```
class VpSnackBar {

  VpSnackBar._privateConstructor();

  static final VpSnackBar instance = VpSnackBar._privateConstructor();

  static void show(String title, String body) {
    Get.snackbar(title, body, snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
  }
  
}
```

I would have to call it like `VpSnackBar.show(title, body);`. But then I'm like should I just make a plain class with a static method which would do what this does, without ever being instantiated? Is instantiation beneficial?

Another option is a global function with an uppercase name so it is used like a class:

```
void VpSnackBar(String title, String body) {
  Get.snackbar(title, body, snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
}
```

This is the only way that I know how to call it like `VpSnackBar(title, body);`. Which is my preferred way to call it. However, is a global function a bad practice? Could I achieve calling it like `VpSnackBar(title, body);` without a global function? Which way is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So that I can be safe against any potential changes to the package

You won't be in any sort of way.

1. If the package owner decides to completely change the method internals without touching its prototype, you'll still be affected by those changes.
2. If the package owner decides to change the method's prototype in a backwards incompatible way, which features a breaking change, you'll also be affected by those changes.

> I figure it should be a singleton for performance reasons.

I see that you're not running any heavy processes (like IO) when instantiating your class, so I cannot see why you should be concerned about performance. Consider that, for each widget `build()` call, which happens a lot of times in one second, hundreds of classes get instantiated, and they do not affect app's performance.

> However, is a global function a bad practice?

Not at all. The actual problem with your approach is capitalizing the function's first letter. This is a bad practice, since it leaves who's reading to believe that your function call is actually a constructor call.

> Which way is the best practice?

As I stated, I cannot even see a reasonable motive to wrap snackbar in the first place. But leaving this matter apart, each of your solutions seem equally fair to me (as long as you the uncapitalize the first of the function). In such situation, you may want to use the one that you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment, since it's off-topic and highly opinionated: If you care about good practices, stop using `get` right away. I could write an entire article on why it is a terribly bad written.

Comment: Thanks. Wrapping the snack bar decouples my app from the package. If I decide I don’t like Get I can just change my snack bar implementation in one file and keep the contract intact and not have Get littered throughout my app. And I will be far less affected by their changes to the snack bar if they do have breaking changes as I only have to deal with those changes in one file. It also doesn’t sound right to me to not consider performance because allegedly hundreds of classes are being instantiated every build without affecting performance. Sounds like a dangerous mindset to me.

Comment: I got your point about decoupling, but you have to consider that Get deals with snackbar in a very unusual way. For example, if you were to replace Get's snackbar by the built-in snackbar, your contract wouldn't be left as it is because you'd need `BuildContext` as a parameter.

Comment: I must insist that your concern about performance is not necessary. It's a premature optimization, since you didn't evaluate whether it impacts on your app's performance. It's actually hard to tell whether a certain optimization has any value. In fact, they can even worsen performance. This is because compilers do a lot of magic and processors don't work in a intuitive way. 

At such a high programming level, it's impossible to say a certain optimization is beneficial without benchmark.

Comment: That's true about the Get Snackbar. Get SnackBar is too vastly different from the  Flutter SnackBar, such that they cannot be easily swapped out for one another. Bit of a shame.  And true there is no way I will impact performance negatively in this task.